# knockoutjs, Checkboxes are checks with delay

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

source is here
http://jsfiddle.net/M8KFd/302/
if you press on animal's name - all works well. But if you press on checkbox then animal will be picked but checkbos isn't checked. Any ideas?
I want do it without property .isSelected() to all my animals

Comment: Your checkbox list binded to anials array. But this array is not observable property of your ViewModel, so when your viewmodel was changed this global array (animal) actually does not changed and knockout will not update checkbox list.

In order to solve this problem you need to implement animals array as observeble property of binded viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nyt5q/1/) a modified version of your fiddle.

The main changes are these:

1. The checkboxes are grouped using the "name" attribute. I gave the "animals" name, but with no relation to the model.
2. The animals arrays belongs to the model
3. The checked attribute is bound like this `checked: $parent.selectedAnimals`. *selectedAnimals* is an array of animals ids. Knockout.js keeps the track.
4. New bindings on each input: `value: id, attr: {id: id}`. Once the inputs get the values same as the ids of the animals in the selectedAnimals array, Knockout.js knows how to amend this array, by id.
5. **selectAll** function copies the id of each animal from animals array to selectedAnimals array. Once again Knockout.js updates the UI.

And some labels

Comment: Note that, according to the html specifications, the id attribute should not start with a number. Letters and underscores are fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the order of events.
The checked evalutaion is done when you check the checkbox; at that time the item is not in the selectedItems. Next time the evaluation is done it still is so that explains the delay.

I forked your Fiddle to make your example work (except for the select all)

http://jsfiddle.net/dyKvQ/

Comment: No, I want do it without .isSelected()

Comment: your fiddle doesn't keep his existing functionality.  Not doing a -1, but letting you know your "fix" is broken.